# Trouble to add numbers using foreach

Tags: php

```
$sql3=mysql_query("select serialno from milestone where (serialno ='".$serialno."')");<br/>
$promatch3=mysql_num_rows($sql3);
if($promatch3 > 0)
{
    $sql2=mysql_query("select serialno from milestone where (serialno >='".$serialno."')");
    {
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
    {
        $jes3[]=$row2['serialno'];
    }

}
}
$jes4=implode(",",$jes3);
$jes5=array();
$jes5=explode(",",$jes4);
foreach($jes5 as $jes6)
{
    $sql6=mysql_query("update milestone set serialno='".$jes6."' +1 where serialno='".$jes6."'");
}
```

I have one table field serial no when I add serial no It should insert.like(1,2,3..),I can insert values..after adding this serial no If I supposed add serial no 2 in the serial no field It should be add as a new value and previous serial no 2 should be 3,3 should be 4,4 should be 5,and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple options. The easiest would be to add in PHP.

```
$newVal = $jes6+1;
$sql6=mysql_query("update milestone set serialno='". $newVal ."'  where serialno='".$jes6."'");
```

Comment: Thats Right,but This is not A single value It should be increment all greater values..Please Help ME....